# Problem to understand the proof : $\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists \delta >0: m(E)<\delta \implies \int_E|f|<\varepsilon $

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb R^d)$. Then, for all $\varepsilon >0$ there is $\delta >0$ s.t. for all measurable set $E\subset \mathbb R^d$ s.t. $m(E)<\delta $, we have $$\int_E|f|<\varepsilon .$$

---

The proof goes as follow : let $\varepsilon >0$ and set $F_n=\{x\mid |f|\leq n\}$. Set $f_N(x)=f(x)\boldsymbol 1_{F_n}$. Then $|f_N|$ is an increasing and non negative sequence. By Monotone convergence theorem, there is $N$ s.t. $$\int (|f|-|f_N|)<\frac{\varepsilon }{2}.$$

Let $\delta >0$ s.t. $\delta N<\frac{\varepsilon }{2}$. Then, if $m(E)<\delta $,
$$\int_E|f|\leq \int(|f|-|f_n|)+\int_{E}|f_N|\leq \frac{\varepsilon }{2}+Nm(E)\leq \varepsilon .$$

---

My problem : I have doubt with this proof since for me $\delta $ depend on $\varepsilon $ (of course) and $N$ (that's not good since $\delta $ should depend on $\varepsilon $ only). Don't we have a problem ? (it's an official solution, so the solution should be correct). Could someone explain ?

Comment: Of course $\delta$ should depend on $\varepsilon$. It says "for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is $\delta$...". $N$ depends on $f$ and yes $\delta$ depends on $f$. (It is impossible to find a delta that does not depend on $f$, also for many $f$'s it is impossible to find a delta that does not depend on epsilon.)

Comment: @Yanko: The problem it's that $\delta $ should depend on $\varepsilon $ only, not on $N$.

Comment: Your $N$ is a fixed constant which depends only on $\epsilon$ (and $f$), so there is no problem with $\delta$ depending on $N$, i.e. implicitly it only depends on $\epsilon$.